# Doctrine2 Integer type with specified length

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I'm making a symfony2 project using Doctrine 2 and i'm using Annotations to map my entities to a MySQL database.
I have read doctrine 2 documentation and it says that the length attribute applies only to the string type.

So my question is, is there a way to set a specific length (so no smallint, bigint and so on...) of an integer column through annotations (other than columnDefinition) and if not...why there isn't any? In Doctrine 1 i could specify a certain specific length for integer types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Doctrine is created for manipulating data using itself. And it is not care how this data will be displayed by another programs. But length definition for numeric values exist only for convenient displaying data in DB-managers (mostly for cli mysql client).

In Doctrine you also cannot create triggers for the same reason. You can implement such trigger with doctrine.

Comment: It's not about data display, it's about database design. The last time i have checked setting fields length when you know they will store only data with a certain length at max helps with optimization and i don't really need an 11 digits field to store the number of hours per day i've been at work. You could specify fields length in Doctrine 1

Comment: You need to read more about types in MySQL. INTEGER type always persisted in Database as 4 bytes. If you need less you can use TINYINT (1 byte), SMALLINT (2 bytes), MEDIUMINT (3 bytes).
When you define INTEGER field in MYSQL with parameter in parenthesis it is only means that this integer value will be displayed in column with size you specified (rest part will be truncated)

Comment: You are actually right and i didn't know that, it was quite surprising indeed. Thanks

Comment: Although (leaving this just as precisation) it must be noted that doctrine 1 did actually use smallint, mediumint and so on based on the length you specified in the schema configuration. For example "type: integer(2)" created a smallint in the database. Probably they thought it's a best practice to explicitly type the kind of field you want rather than base it on visualization choices. I'm still embarassed by the fact that for all these years i used the notation in a wrong way but i'm glad i got to know it in the end.